# How to install php-chilkat extension on ubuntu with ZTS enabled

Tags: php, chilkat

I am trying to use chilkat php extension with pthreads extension. So I have ubuntu, php 7.2 with ZTS enabled and pthreads extension. As usual I have downloaded chilkat extension placed .so file into extensions folder and enabled chilkat extension in the php.ini file.

I have the following php startup error:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'chilkat_9_5_0.so' (tried: /etc/php7/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20170718/chilkat_9_5_0.so (/etc/php7/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20170718/chilkat_9_5_0.so: undefined symbol: compiler_globals), /etc/php7/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20170718/chilkat_9_5_0.so.so (/etc/php7/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20170718/chilkat_9_5_0.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Also I have tried to build extension from source here https://github.com/chilkatsoft/Chilkat-PHP-Extension But I don't know what does mean 'phpIncludeDir' ? What the folder exactly should I use ?

Comment: The error message seems to be clear to me: No such file or directory

Comment: I have updated the question. Also I have reused another chilkat version. The error is a bit different - 'undefined symbol: compiler_globals'. I am 100% sure the extension is placed in right directory

Comment: Looks like a doubled file extension: chilkat_9_5_0.so.so so maybe your shoudl remove the .so extension from your code.

Comment: same result, 'undefined symbol: compiler_globals'

Comment: Then maybe this links helps you: http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?t=22958

Comment: Might be a 32/64 bit problem, or a thread safe vs non thread safe.

Comment: I use exactly 64 bit version for my 64 bit system. Most likely thread safe problem

Answer (score 1):

The Chilkat PHP builds are for PHP without ZTS enabled.  Here are new builds with ZTS enabled.  If these work fine, then they'll be available starting with the next version of Chilkat.

https://chilkatdownload.com/prerelease/chilkat-9.5.0-php-zts-7.2-x86_64-linux-1388.tar.gz
https://chilkatdownload.com/prerelease/chilkat-9.5.0-php-zts-7.3-x86_64-linux-1389.tar.gz
https://chilkatdownload.com/prerelease/chilkat-9.5.0-php-zts-7.2-x86-linux-1390.tar.gz
https://chilkatdownload.com/prerelease/chilkat-9.5.0-php-zts-7.3-x86-linux-1391.tar.gz

Note: The above pre-release URLs will not remain valid forever..

Comment: Thank u a lot for help, but it doesn't work. I tried first link. I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, 64-bit, PHP 7.2.2 (cli) (built: Feb 14 2019 13:47:03) ( ZTS DEBUG )
The error is:
Warning: PHP Startup: chilkat_9_5_0: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20170718,TS
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20170718,TS,debug
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0